# How to reset headers or recreate request in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Only first call acquire headers. Next calls with different headers give same results and seems headers doen not changed:

```
describe "whoami" do
  context 'members' do
    before {
      get "/api/v1/whoami", {}, token_sign_in(user1)
      p request.body # => 'user1'
      get "/api/v1/whoami", {}, token_sign_in(user2)
      p request.body # => 'user1'
    }

    it "am I user2" do
       get "/api/v1/whoami", {}, token_sign_in(user2)
       p request.body # => 'user1'
    end
  end
end
```

All next results maked with same user. Possible it is not headers problem but keep-alive or some like this. (or is it bug?)

How to reset headers or connection? And how to recreate request?